# Get a value from a dictionary without linking to the memory location

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

In Python 3.4, I'm trying to retrieve a value from a dictionary, change it and have it used somewhere else in the program, but I've found that dictionaries demonstrate the following behaviour:

```
>>> D = {"A":[1,2,3]}
>>> C = D["A"]
>>> C.append(4)
>>> D["A"]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> F = D.get("A")
>>> F.append(5)
>>> D["A"]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Is there a way around this so I can assign the value from a dictionary to a variable without them linking like this?

Comment: Would copy of the list be enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dictionaries doesn't preserves the objects values just a reference to objects.

You need to assign a copy of the list to another variable name, you can use `[:]` to create a shallow copy :

```
>>> D = {"A":[1,2,3]}
>>> C = D["A"][:]
>>> C.append(4)
>>> D["A"]
[1, 2, 3]
```

Or use `copy` module :

```
>>> import copy
>>> C = copy.copy(D["A"])
>>> C.append(4)
>>> D["A"]
[1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

A very simple solution would be to make copy of the list inside the dictionary using `[:]` and then use it.

Example -

```
>>> D = {"A":[1,2,3]}
>>> C = D["A"][:]
>>> C.append(4)
>>> C
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> D["A"]
[1, 2, 3]
```

Please note this would make copy of the list .